# Define last week from [date]

Tags: database, powerbi, dax

I have issue extracting week/year from DATE column.

We are in week 02 of 2022 and my goal is to set MAX week to be "01 2022" at the moment.

Goal is to have dynamic calculated column or measure that will always show previous week.

```
weekMax = FORMAT(MAX(fact[date]),"WW YYYY")
```

With this solution it is showing me 03 2022 result.

Is there a way to sort this out?

Comment: Why did you tag PowerShell?

Comment: sorry I misclicked it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
weekMax = 
VAR lastweek = FORMAT(DATEADD('Table'[Date].[Date], -7, DAY) ,"WW YYYY")

RETURN
IF(FORMAT(TODAY() - 7 ,"WW YYYY") = lastweek, lastweek, BLANK())
```

**Output:**

[image]

---

Or if you always just want the last week without considering any columns, you can use:

```
weekMax = FORMAT(TODAY() - 7 ,"WW YYYY")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is almost what I need. 
Issue is that I want just latest week to be shown, not weeks in past..

Comment: I've updated it with two suggestions. Could you check and give feedback?